# Research trends on mean curvature flow

Tags: differential-geometry, research, mean-curvature-flows

It's been a few months since I've been curious about mean curvature flow and now I'm reading [Robert Haslhofer's lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7765). I like the subject and would like to do research on it, but I know neither where to start nor current research trends.

Can anyone explain the main threads of research in this area, please?

Thank you in advance.